# Java Guice - how to bind integer value to my class/object?

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I don't understand how can I simply bind any value when I bind a class. I always get this error:

```
No implementation for test.Triangle annotated with @com.google.inject.name.Named(value=triangle) was bound.
```

I tried this:

**Triangle class**

```
@Inject
public void setLength(@Named("triangle") int length) {
    this.length = length;
}
```

**Configuration class**

`bind(Triangle.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("triangle")).toInstance(1); //this one just gives error that I can't do that.`

How can I enter a value into it, so it would use setLength method with my chosen value?.. I read Guice documentation, but didn't find it. In Spring framework such things like these seemed much easier to do and understand (maybe it has better documentation, at least for me). Also if I missed in documentation where it shows this kind of thing you can link it too.

Comment: Did you try using `Integer` instead?

Comment: You mean in setLength method or where? Isn't there a way to just simply show for Guice that it should assign the value? Like in spring you can simply do something like `<constructor-arg type="int" value="1"/>`

Comment: I mean replacing `int length` with `BigInteger length`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```java
bind(Integer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("triangle")).toInstance(1);
```

You don't want to bind `Triangle` to 1 - you want to bind `Integer` to 1. It might be better to use `@Named("triangleLength")` or even switch to a binding annotation (`@IndicatesTriangleLength`) to make the intention clear.