# Guice injection of primitive fails through provider even after binding

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice

I have a class that looks like

```
class MyClass {
    private final int size;

    @Inject
    public MyClass(final int size) {
        this.a = a;
    }
}
```

My module class that provides an instance of `MyClass` looks like

```
public class MyClassModule extends AbstractModule {

@Override
protected void configure() {
    bind(Integer.class).annotatedWith(Names.named("size")).toInstance(1000);
}

@Provides
@Singleton
public MyClass providesMyClass(@Named("size") int size) {
    return new MyClass(size)
}
```

When my application class uses an object of `MyClass` I see this error -

```
 com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors: | 1) Could not find a suitable constructor in java.lang.Integer. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private. |   at java.lang.Integer.class(Integer.java:52) |   while locating java.lang.Integer |     for parameter 0
```

Where is it going wrong? (Not a duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20731500/java-guice-how-to-bind-integer-value-to-my-class-object) as I am not injecting the variable directly to the class but through a provider)

Comment: `int.class` still isn't `Integer.class`

Comment: @chrylis When I changed the binding from `Integer.class` to `int.class`, I still got the same error

Comment: please, show code,where instance of `MyClass` is injected. I tried to run your code with `Guice.createInjector(new MyClassModule()).getInstance(MyClass.class)` and everything works fine